# I want to change file upload size limit

Tags: javascript, cpanel, file-sharing

I am testing a script on my domain sharemb.com. It says file too large when I upload a file of more than 2MB, where I want to put 30MB setting default. Where to find it and change?

Comment: Wow, that depends on a lot of things. What host are you using, what HTTP Server, are you trying to upload in cpanel, or in you app. Please tell us the context of your file upload, and give us more specifics about your environment and application.

Answer (score 0):

change code

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    maxFiles: 3,
    maxFilesize: 2,
```

to

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    maxFiles: 3,
    maxFilesize: 30,
```

Comment: Prodip Das thanks for response
but where to find that code to be changed?

Comment: You can search/find the text 


'myDropzone is the configuration for the element that has an id'

Answer (score 0):

[image]

find this code in your editor and change here

Comment: Thank You Bro you made me do it and i put it 10MB limit now [link] (http://sharemb.com)

Comment: Please add code as text, not images. Images are not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers.